# VaadinService.getCurrentRequest() is returning HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am new to Vaadin, I am setting up a project in our GCP environment. The app itself running with HTTPS protocol with the certificates and whatnot. On top of that we have an internal HTTPS and a TCP load balancer to access the webpage from our network. The code snippet is as follows

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) VaadinService.getCurrentRequest();
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
String uri = request.getRequestURI();
String ctx = request.getContextPath();
baseUrl = getBaseUrl(url, uri, ctx);
```

My loadbalancer URL is

> https://somehost:someport/path

Somehow VaadinService.getCurrentRequest() is returning HTTP instead of HTTPS. The weird thing is that it happens only in GCP environment. It works fine in my local system. I have asked our network team to also look into things from GCP side.

Am I missing something here, am I configuring something wrong here. Can someone please help a buddy out.

Comment: This may happen if the load balancer do not set the X-Forwarded-Proto header. Did you checked that all needed forward headers are set?

Comment: @MarcoC Thanks for the reply. I will check with our team.